# Syntax errors in blades Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am migrating from Laravel 4.3 to 5.3 and things are going fine except one thing, I can`t properly debug blade syntax errors.

For example I had a typo in my blade, the typo was in a file home.blade.php, but the error is reported like this:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
FatalErrorException in c53354289a35d504fdc7d35ecbfb9b4348f1f804.php line 25:
syntax error, unexpected ';'
```

In laravel 4.3 and bellow blade file name is also reported. With this system it's hard to track down error unless I look at the compiled view, which is a hassle. Am I missing something here?

Comment: How are you viewing this error? i.e. is it in the browser or in your log file or somewhere else?

Comment: @RossWilson in browser

Answer (score 0):

The name is coming from storage/framework/views/

check the content of the file and you can find the view

Comment: I know about that, but when I have over 100 blade files its a pain to find the right one, I would like to get the blade name.

Comment: @VladimirSabo Find the file `c53354289a35d504fdc7d35ecbfb9b4348f1f804.php` and look at its contents. Which Blade file it is should be pretty obvious when you look at its code.

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed a little struggle to find the file you are looking for. The only way I got this to work properly is to put a little HTML comment in the blade files, with the correspondig view filename. That way, you can extract the original blade file from the compiled one.

You can try something like this (in your views):

```
@section('content')
  <!-- VIEW: this/view/file.blade.php -->

  // content goes here
@endsection
```